# What are the settings.py credentials for SMS in DJANGO of integrating the third party API like SMSBOX, other than TIWILIO

Tags: python, django, sms-gateway

What will be the credentials in `settings.py`, to send this `sms` via third party `api`. Like where to give `HOST_NAME, PASSWORD, API_KEY`?

```
message = SmsMessage(body='Project Created', from_phone='+923117593775', to=['+923411727228'])
message.send()
```

Comment: To print text in bolt and in capital letters won't make an answer arive earlier. Bolt text is made to make it easier to understand a question. In your question this is not the case. Please update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python's [request](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library for making requests to APIs. SMSBox has different APIs for accessing the services. [This one](https://www.smsbox.com/API/SendShortMessage) is for sending a SMS.

```
import requests
from django.conf import settings

def sendSMS(message, from ,to):
    url = 'https://www.smsbox.com/SMSGateway/Services/Messaging.asmx/Http_SendSMS'
    payload = {
        "username": settings.SMSUsername,
        "password": settings.SMSPassword,
        "customerId": settings.SMSCutomerID,
        "senderText": settings.SMSSenderName,
        "messageBody": str(message),
        "recipientNumbers": ','.join(to),
        "isBlink": False,
        "isFlash": False
    }
    response = request.post(url, payload)
```

Now in your settings.py, you can have the required setting variables

```
SMSUsername = 'your_username'
SMSPassword = 'your_password'
SMSCutomerID = 'your_customer_id'
SMSSenderName  'sms_sender_name'
```

Twilio has a supported python SDK package for integration of its services, so you can directly implement it, but for platforms who don't have SDK support for python/django, you can use `requests` library to call APIs as per their documentation.
This function was made according to the documentation provided by [SMSBox](https://www.smsbox.com/API/SendShortMessage), you can create your own functions as per your requirement and the API documentation.

Comment: Welcome @USAMAREHMANYOUSAF, if this answer solved your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Yes this, perfectly solve the answer, I am trying to mark it up but not have enough reputations according to the credentials of StackOverFlow. But thanks a lot Sir. @Aakash_Srivastava.